# How to get the element(s) with the certain class name in nav bar?

Tags: jquery

Assume i have this `navbar` structure:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="menuitems">

                    <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=1">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=2">Reds</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=3">Whites</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=4">Sparkling</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=5">Hidden Label</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=6">Mixed Cases</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=7">Spirits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=8">Beer &amp; Cider</a></li>
                </ul>
```

when i click on a link, i want to remove the class "active" from all `<li>` tags and attach it to the `<li>` tag of the clicked link, how do i do it?

Comment: `$('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active')` for click event `$(this).addClass('active')`

Comment: Use: `$(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');`

Comment: on click of your link it will redirect on  next page right, it means you want active class on next page?

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes u replied first and your answer worked so if want points please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the class you can use below line

```
$('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active')`
```

click event

```
$('ul.nav > li').on('click',function(){
  $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below JS, this will work only if onclick of link your page is not redirecting on other page.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar-nav li a').click(function(){
     $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
     });
 });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="menuitems">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Reds</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Whites</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=4">Sparkling</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=5">Hidden Label</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=6">Mixed Cases</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=7">Spirits</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Product/GetProductByCategoryForMasterMenu?CategoryId=8">Beer &amp; Cider</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what happens if he has multiple menius witch use the same classes `.navbar-nav` and `.active`?

Comment: @madalinivascu we can use any specific class or ID of that element other then this we can specify the sturcture with parent class , there are multiple ways to do this I just wrote here assuming that right now we have only one UL element

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('.nav li').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('ul.nav').find('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```